# Data frame transformation in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame which I want to transform:

```
ID       Level        Band      Date
1        A            A1        2020-06-01
1        B            B1        2020-06-03
1        C            C1        2020-06-04
```

to

```
ID       First_Level      Second_Level    Third_Level  First_Band   Second_Band  Third_Band      First_Data   Second_Date     Third_Date
1        A                B                C           A1            B1          C1             2020-06-01   2020-06-03     2020-06-04
```

and this is a sample data. There are multiple IDs, levels, bands and associated dates. How to achieve the solution for this problem?

Comment: do you have repeated IDs?

Comment: @anky: Nope all the IDs are unique

Comment: In that case , my below answer should work for you

Comment: Perfect! I will check and accept in a while :) Thanks

Comment: i had a typo in my code.. just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach for dynamic renaming:

```
import inflect
e = inflect.engine()

s = df.set_index('ID').stack()
idx_1 = (s.index.get_level_values(1) + 
         s.groupby(s.index).cumcount().add(1).map(e.ordinal).radd('_'))
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((s.index.get_level_values(0),idx_1))
print(s.unstack())
```

---

[image]

Comment: I did not get the correct output form. The data seems to be correct but my output is coming out to be like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580244/data-frame-index-transformation-in-pandas Could you check and let me know the reason? after using your code I did this : df_ = pd.DataFrame(s).T

Comment: @Django0602 I am not able to reproduce the same, this answered the way you had asked, may be if you can add a sample data to the question and show how did you reach there it would help. I am guessing you dont need the unstack in the end..? or `s.unstack().reset_index().T` , any one of them..

Comment: You are totally correct.. s.unstack() worked. I was doing a silly mistake!

Comment: @Django0602 happens to all of us  no big deal :-) Cheers..!!

Comment: just one more question, one of my columns have 12 distinct values so when the code splits it there are 12 new columns and the naming convention is correct but the order is like this `band_12th band_11th band_10th band_1st band_2nd` . How do I sort this correctly?

Comment: @Django0602 can you test `import natsort as ns` and then `df[ns.natsorted(df.columns)]`

Comment: Amazing! sorted!