# Data frame index transformation in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, reshape, reindex

I want to trasnform the following data frame:

```
 ID 1234
     type   band    category
  0    A      B       C
```

to:

```
ID     type   band   category
1234     A      B      C
```

where ID is the index column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df.stack(0).reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     ID Type band category
0  1234    A    B        C
```